# How to actually modify values of an XML file using XML::LibXML

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, vmware, xml-libxml

I have an XML file (`information.xml`). I have to extract element and attribute values from this XML file and insert those element and attribute values into another XML file (`build.xml`). I have to change the `build.xml` file by filling the appropriate element values and tags from `information.xml` file.

I have to use XML::LibXML to do so. I am able to extract the element and attribute values from `information.xml`. But, I am unable to open and fill those values in `build.xml`

Example :

`information.xml`

```
<info>
  <app version="10.5.10" long_name ="My Application">
    <name> MyApp </name>
    <owner>larry </owner>
    <description> This is my first application</description>
  </app>
</info>
```

`build.xml`

```
<build long_name="" version="">
  <section type="Appdesciption">
    <description> </description>
  </section>
  <section type="Appdetails">
    <app_name> </app_name>
    <owner></owner>
  </section>
</build>
```

Now, my task is to extract value of owner from `information.xml`, open `build.xml`, search for owner tag in `build.xml` and put the extracted value there.

The Perl script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
my $file1="/root/shubhra/myapp/information.xml";
my $file2="/root/shubhra/myapp/build.xml";

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($file1);
foreach my $line ($doc->findnodes('//info/app'))
{
    my $owner= $line->findnodes('./owner');  # 1st way
    print "\n",$owner->to_literal,"\n";

    my ($long_name) = $line->findvalue('./@long_name');  # 2nd way
    print "\n $long_name \n";

    my $version = $line->findnodes('@version');
    print "\n",$version->to_literal,"\n";
}

my $parser2 = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc2 = $parser2->parse_file($file2);
foreach my $line2 ($doc2->findnodes('//build'))
{
    my ($owner2)= $line2->findnodes('./section/owner/text()');

    my ($version2)=$line2->findvalue('./@version');

    print "\n Build.xml already has version : $version2 \n";
    print "\n Build.xml already has owner :",$owner2->to_literal;

    $owner2->setData("Windows Application 2"); # Not changing build.xml
    $line2->setAttribute(q|version|,"60.60.60");  # Not changing build.xml 
    my $changedversion = $line2->getAttribute(q|version|); 
    #superficially changed but didn't changed build.xml content
    print "\n The changed version is : $changedversion";
}
```

`build.xml` looks like :

```
<build long_name="" version="9.10.10">
<section type="Appdesciption">
<description> </description>
</section>
<section type="Appdetails">
<app_name> </app_name>
<owner>shubhra</owner>
</section>
</build>
```

```
my $doc3 = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file2, no_blanks => 1);
my $xpath_expression = '/build/section/owner/text()';
my @nodes = $doc3->findnodes( $xpath_expression );
for my $node (@nodes) {
    my $content = $node->toString;
    $content = $owner;
    $node->setData($content);
}
$doc->toFile($file2 . '.new', 1);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can't you think of any DOM methods that might be useful? Perhaps you want to re-read the documentation on [DOM nodes](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML::Node) and [XML elements](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML::Element).

Comment: I tried doing so by using findnode and findvalue option. Using findnode, I go to the particular node and using findvalue I extract the output in a variable. But, when i am trying to put that variable value in build.xml, i am unable to change the content.

Comment: OP, you need to show what you've done so we can help you. I don't see what you've been trying in terms of Perl code for the past 3 days.

Comment: Okay.wait. i will add the code here. I am making use of "setData()" to change element value. Do, I need to load the xml to actually change the content of xml file. Also, i need to make use of Xml::LIBXML only, as this is part of my old code.

Comment: I added the perl script. i need to change or add the content of build.xml. How to do it ? setData() and setAttribute() is not changing the content of buils.xml file. Please Help!

Comment: Well, this is like complaining that `while (<$fh>) { $_ = 42 }` doesn't change the input file. The DOM is not magically tied to a file, it is a seperate in-memory representation. You have to write the document back to the file yourself, e.g. `use File::Slurp; write_file "output.xml", { binmode => ':utf8' }, $doc2->toString`.

Comment: @amon: I added/changed the below code. I made use of load_xml command. But, I am unable to understand, how come it filled the values for all elements/attribute tags (when I gave the xpath_expression for owner tag only)

Comment: @amon: I am able to solve the problem. At the end of code, it should be $doc3 instead of $doc, while using toFile() function.

Answer (score 4):

The following fails to find anything (setting `$owner2` to `undef`) since `owner` has no text:

```
my ($owner2) = $line2->findnodes('./section/owner/text()');
```

You want

```
my ($owner2) = $line2->findnodes('./section/owner');
```

This entails changing

```
print "\n Build.xml already has owner :", $owner2->to_literal;
```

to

```
print "\n Build.xml already has owner :", $owner2->textContent;
```

and

```
$owner2->setData("Windows Application 2");
```

to

```
$owner2->removeChildNodes();
$owner2->appendText("Windows Application 2");
```

---

You imply you want the following to change `build.xml`, but it doesn't even mention `build.xml`:

```
$line2->setAttribute(q|version|, "60.60.60");
```

It does modify `$doc2`, but you'll need to add the following code to modify `build.xml` too:

```
$doc2->toFile('build.xml');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping and letting me know the chnages. I am new to Libxml module. But, could you please explain by example :---> why you are making use of removeChildNodes() function. What if , if I have "many nodes/elements" with the "same name" are present under one tag. Example : If I have total 3 disk's  under main tag disk. Tags look like :   <disks> <disk id="1"> </disk> <disk id="2"></disk> <disk id="3"> <disk> </disks>

Comment: Could you please explain!

Comment: Re "why you are making use of removeChildNodes() function.", to remove any existing text node before adding a new one.

Comment: Re "What if , if I have 'many nodes/elements' with the 'same name'", Are you asking how to extract them? `my @disks = $disks->findnodes('disk');` or  `my @disks = $parent_of_disks->findnodes('disks/disk');`

Comment: Could you please answer...appendText is not working! -ikegami

Comment: $owner2->removeChildNodes();
     $owner2->appendText("Ankit Garg owner"); # Not working, error         Can't locate object method "appendText" via package "XML::LibXML::Text" at  myscript.pl line 38.

Comment: @Stano : So bad of them...rejected the edit. Anyways, i solved the problem on my own...huh!

Comment: @Shubhra Garg, `Can't locate object method "appendText" via package "XML::LibXML::Text"` means you're trying to add a text node as a child of text node, which makes no sense since text nodes can't have children. You ignored the fix to the problem you actually asked about, which is to remove `/text()`. Please reread the answer and spend time actually understanding it.

Comment: setAttribute doesn't work with lower version of Libxml....version 1.18. Could you please help ?

Comment: Let's say I believe what you say. Your asking about a bug in a version of XML::LibXML that's 13 years old. My answer is: It's been fixed in newer versions.

Comment: i am in serious trouble ikegami.I am using lower version of Libxml 1.18. I am not supposed to use higher version of Libxml.Otherwise, i wouldn't have asked for your help! Could you please let me know the solution if duplicate elements are present. removeChildNodes() doesn't work for Libxml 1.18 version. I need to updated only 1 node out of 4 duplicate nodes. I am attaching the example above, I need to update VirtualQunatity (say 4), if resourceType is 3. But, the below tag for VirtualQuanity also gets updated.

Comment: Could you please help with the above mentioned problem. @ikegami

Comment: 1) Comments are not the place to ask new questions. 2) What's "Libxml"? (XML::LibXML? libxml2?) 3) What do you want? You say the version of something you're using is broken, but you're not willing to upgrade. [These are not questions you should answer here. These are things you should consider when posting your question in the appropriate place.]

Comment: I am sorry ikegami...it is the same XML::LibXML. And, only the version is lower.